# Decode character set in json and pretty print

Tags: python, json, api, character-encoding, instagram

Get A result from instagram API call , How to decode those \u064a, \u0644 characters?

 I tried python json dumps and json loads with pretty print , it doesnt print it nicely.

I am also not sure these \u062d\u0633... etc  is something i needed ?

What are these things representing... Thanks in advance

```
 {u'meta': {u'code': 200}, u'data': [{u'username': u'xxxxxxx', u'bio':     
u'\u062d\u0633\u0627\u0628 \u062f\u0639\u0648\u064a \u064a\u062d\u0645\u0644 
\u0628\u0639\u0636 \u062a\u0635\u0627\u0645\u064a\u0645\u064a 
\u0648\u0627\u0644\u0628\u0639\u0636 \u0645\u0645\u0627 \u0631\u0627\u0642 \u0644\u064a 
\u0635\u0648\u0631\u064a \u062d\u0644\u0627\u0644 \u0644\u0644\u062c\u0645\u064a\u0639 
\u0645\u0642\u0627\u0628\u0644 \u062f\u0639\u0648\u0647 \u0635\u0627\u062f\u0642\u0647 
\u0627\u0646\u0634\u0631 \u0644\u064a\u0633\u062a\u0641\u064a\u062f 
\u0627\u0644\u062c\u0645\u064a\u0639 ( \u0627\u0644\u062f\u0627\u0644 \u0639\u0644\u0649 
\u0627\u0644\u062e\u064a\u0631 \u0643\u0641\u0627\u0639\u0644\u0647 )', u'website':
```

Comment: The bio is in unicode, `\u062d` is an [arabic character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/62d/index.htm).

Comment: u'' - unicode string in python2.x, \u062c is a unicode character, you can print it on screen with print like ```print you_var['data'][0]['bio']```

Answer (score 1):

they are not anything special ... its just a unicode codepoint ... when you print it you will not see the u

```
print response["data"][0]["bio"]
```

or

```
some_string = u'''\u062d\u0633\u0627\u0628 \u062f\u0639\u0648\u064a   
                \u064a\u062d\u0645\u0644 \u0628\u0639\u0636 
                \u062a\u0635\u0627\u0645\u064a\u0645\u064a 
                \u0648\u0627\u0644\u0628\u0639\u0636 \u0645\u0645\u0627           
                \u0631\u0627\u0642 \u0644\u064a 
                \u0635\u0648\u0631\u064a \u062d\u0644\u0627\u0644 
                \u0644\u0644\u062c\u0645\u064a\u0639 
                \u0645\u0642\u0627\u0628\u0644 \u062f\u0639\u0648\u0647 
                \u0635\u0627\u062f\u0642\u0647 
                \u0627\u0646\u0634\u0631 \u0644\u064a\u0633\u062a\u0641\u064a\u062f 
                \u0627\u0644\u062c\u0645\u064a\u0639 ( \u0627\u0644\u062f\u0627\u0644      \u0639\u0644\u0649 
        \u0627\u0644\u062e\u064a\u0631 \u0643\u0641\u0627\u0639\u0644\u0647 )'''

print some_string
```

note that whatever you are printing to will need to understand unicode (IE DOS console does not work ...)